# 特定の要素だけ残してページ遷移をする方法

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

まずはこのサイトをみてほしいです。
→http://kekselias.com/

左のナビゲーションでどれかクリックするとメインの要素が右にスライドして消え、
次の要素が左からスライドしてきます。

このアニメーションでわかないのが、urlが変わってるにもかかわらず、左のヘッダーは
一瞬も消えることなく常に表示されています。

urlでページを変えつつも、ヘッダー（特定の要素）だけ残してページを遷移させる方法を知りたいです。

わかる方がいらしたら教えてほしいです。

自分自身の知識は、HTMLとCSSとjQueryがすこしだけ書ける程度なので
あまり難しい専門用語を使わずに説明していただけると幸いです。

よろしくお願いしますm(_ _)m

Answer (score 5):

HTML5 History APIを使用することで、履歴及びアドレスバーの表示を操作することができます。これにより、ページ遷移したかのように見せかけつつ表示するコンテンツを切り替えることができます。
例えばGoogleの検索・検索結果ページなんかもページ遷移は発生していません。

参考： [ブラウザの履歴を操作する](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます！